# Floating point calculations and the triangle inequality

Tags: floating-point, distance, trigonometry, nearest-neighbor

I am using a VPTree to optimize some K-Nearest neighbors algorithms.

A VPTree requires that a distance function satisfy the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

The triangle inequality states that the following must be true:

```
distance(x,z) <= distance(x,y) + distance(y,z)
```

One of the features used in our distance function is geographic distance, in meters, which is calculated with floating point arithmetic. I found that this feature has been violating the triangle inequality due to inexact floating point calculations.

For Example:

```
x = -90,-180
y = -90,-162
z = -81,-144
distance(x,z) = 1005162.6564502382
distance(x,y) = 1.2219041408558764E-10
distance(y,z) = 1005162.656450238
distance(x,y) + distance(y,z) = 1005162.6564502381
```

Obviously the triangle inequality has failed in this case.

I was messing around and found that if I round the distance in meters DOWN to the next integer, ie Math.floor() in java, and then add 5, the result seems to all of a sudden satisfy the triangle inequality in all cases I have tested.

I have tested every lat/long combination that is a multiple of 10, ie 20^6 combinations.

After this change we get the following results for the example above:

```
x = -90,-180
y = -90,-162
z = -81,-144
distance(x,z) = 1005167
distance(x,y) = 5
distance(y,z) = 1005167
distance(x,y) + distance(y,z) = 1005172
```

Obviously the triangle inequality no longer fails in this case.

This seems perfect since 5 meters really isn't significant in our use case.

**Am I just "forcing" this to work and am still violating some requirement of the triangle inequality or some requirement of VPTrees? Is this something that is known property of floats?**

Note that simply rounding DOWN without adding 5 does not work.

For Example:

```
x = -90,-180
y = -81,-180
z = -72,-180
distance(x,z) = 2009836.0
distance(x,y) = 1005162.0
distance(y,z) = 1004673.0
distance(x,y) + distance(y,z) = 2009835.0
```

And adding 5:

```
x = -90,-180
y = -81,-180
z = -72,-180
distance(x,z) = 2009841.0
distance(x,y) = 1005167.0
distance(y,z) = 1004678.0
distance(x,y) + distance(y,z) = 2009845.0
```

Also note that I have found that this works for any kind of floating point arithmetic, not just geo distance. For example a distance function that calculates a percentage of some maximum value with a single division operation, as long as you always round to a specific number of digits and add 5 to the last digit.

Comment: Why stop at 5? There are two distances on the right-hand side and one distance on the left-hand side. Add 5 billion millions and the inequality will never be false for triples of points for which it should have been true.

Comment: I understand that. I just used 5 for this example. The question is really more about the triangle inequality, and whether it is truly about just any two distances, or whether it needs to extend to something like any number of distances in some way?

Comment: Relevant: [Why is law of cosines more preferable than haversine when calculating distance between two latitude-longitude points?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4906/why-is-law-of-cosines-more-preferable-than-haversine-when-calculating-distance-b).

Comment: Your distance function must satisfy several properties. The triangle property is one, you say. Another is that it should return the distance between two points to some degree of accuracy. I would be concerned that fudging the distance function in the way you describe compromises the latter requirement. Questions to ask include: Why does your distance function need to satisfy the triangle inequality? Is there some way around that? How accurate does the distance function have to be? Can you calculate it more accurately, so that the rounding errors do not cause violation of the inequality?

Comment: Also note that your sample x and y ((-90º, -180º) and (-90º, -162º)) are two representations of the same point. Modifying your distance function to use a canonical longitude when the latitude is +90º or -90º will eliminate variances that cause violation of the triangle inequality involving these points.

Comment: It does not need to satisfy the triangle inequality. I fact, the algorithm we are applying works perfectly fine currently. It just takes n^2 time to calculate nearest neighbors. A VPTree seems to be the data structure that can reduce that without placing any new requirements on our distance functions other than triangle inequality. (ie some of our "distances" are not really applicable to euclidean space, so any data structure that needs more than just a "distance" will not work.)

Comment: Also, note that I needed to apply this to other features besides geo distance. Geo distance is not the specific problem, it was just a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old thread, but I can’t resist answering.

You method of rounding down and adding five may satisfy the triangle inequality, but it will make the distance between a point and itself greater than zero. That means that:

Distance(x, x) == 5

IMO this is probably as problematic for the VPTree than failing on the triangle inequality property.